# Why OLS Regression gives the lowest MSE results when there are outliers in data

Tags: r, regression

I am dealing with Regression models (Ordinary Least square, Huber Regression, MM Estimator, and Ridge Regression). I would like to check which model is more robust to outliers and multicollinearity simultaneously

However, OLS Regression gives the lowest MSE results when there are outliers and multicollinearity in data compared to other regression models.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

**R-code**

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)

### Calling the important functions ###

# Mean Square meausre: MSE#
mse=function(x){
  mmm=rep(0,ncol(x))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    mmm[i]=mean((x[,i])^2)
  }
  return(mmm)
}

# Mean Absloute Deviation measure: MAD#
mad=function(x){
  mmm=rep(0,ncol(x))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    mmm[i]=mean(abs(x[,i]))
  }
  return(mmm)
}

# mean of the results ##
mee=function(x){
  mmm=rep(0,ncol(x))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    mmm[i]=mean((x[,i]))
  }
  return(mmm)
}

umar <- function(R,n,sig,p,po,py,fx,fy){
  #' where 'R is the level of multicollinearity between 0 and 1'#
  #' "n" is the sample size
  #' "sig" is the error vatiance
  #' "p" is the number of explanaitory variable
  #' 'po' is percentage outlier in x direction
  #'  'py' is percentage outlier in y direction
  #' 'fx' is magnitude of outlier in x direction
  #' 'fy' is magnitude of outlier in y direction'#
  #' RR' is the number of replication 
  
  RR=20      
  set.seed(123)
  
  OP2=NULL
  OP3=NULL
  
  #explanatory vriables
  
  x=matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=p)
  W <-matrix(rnorm(n*(p+1),mean=0,sd=1), n, p+1)  
  for (i in 1:n){
    for (j in 1:p){
      x[i,j] <- sqrt(1-R^2)*W[i,j]+(R)*W[i,p+1];      # Introduce multicollinearity
    }    
  }
  
  b=eigen(t(x)%*%x)$vec[,1]
  
  #Invoking outlier
  rep1=sample(1:n, size=po*n, replace=FALSE)
  x[rep1,2]=fx*max(x[,2])+x[rep1,2]     # the point of outlier
  for (i in 1:RR){
    u=rnorm(n,0,sig)
    y=x%*%b+u
    rep2=sample(1:n, size=py*n, replace=FALSE)
    y[rep2]=fy*max(y)+y[rep2]
    
    dat=data.frame(y,x)
    n=nrow(dat)
    
    # K-fold Cross validation
    #Create k equally size folds
    
    k=3 # number of folds
    folds <- cut(seq(1,n),breaks=k,labels=FALSE)
    
    mols=matrix(0,nrow= k);
    mM=matrix(0,nrow= k);mMM=matrix(0,nrow= k);
    mrls=matrix(0,nrow= k);mrm=matrix(0,nrow= k);mrmm=matrix(0,nrow= k);

    mols2=matrix(0,nrow= k);
    mM2=matrix(0,nrow= k);mMM2=matrix(0,nrow= k)
    mrls2=matrix(0,nrow= k);mrm2=matrix(0,nrow= k);mrmm2=matrix(0,nrow= k);
    
    #Perform 3 fold cross validation
    
    for(i in 1:k){
      #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
      testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
      testData <- dat[testIndexes, ]
      trainData <- dat[-testIndexes, ]
      xtr=as.matrix(trainData[,-1])
      ytr=trainData[,1]
      xte=as.matrix(testData[,-1])
      yte=testData[,1]
      
      mest=rlm(ytr~xtr,psi=psi.huber,k2=1.345,maxit=1000)$coefficients  # Huber Regression 
      
      mmest=rlm(ytr~xtr,method="MM",maxit = 1000)$coefficients  # MM Estimators 
      
      ols=lm(ytr~xtr)$coefficients     # OLS Regression 
      
      nxtr=model.matrix(~xtr)



      ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(nxtr, ytr, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)
      ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se
      
      I=diag(1,ncol(nxtr))
      ridols=solve(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr+ridge.fit.lambda*I)%*%(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr)%*%ols  # Ridge Regression 
      mrls[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridols)^2
      ridM=solve(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr+ridge.fit.lambda*I)%*%(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr)%*%mest # Ridge Huber 
      mrm[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridM)^2
      ridMM=solve(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr+ridge.fit.lambda*I)%*%(t(nxtr)%*%nxtr)%*%mmest # Ridge MM
      mrmm[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridMM)^2


      mols[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ols)^2
      mM[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%mest)^2
      mMM[i]=mean(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%mmest)^2
      
      mrls2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridols))
      mrm2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridM))
      mrmm2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ridMM))
      mols2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%ols))
      mM2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%mest))
      mMM2[i]=mean(abs(yte-cbind(1,xte)%*%mmest))
      
    }
    
    res1=cbind(mols,mM,mMM,
               mrls,mrm,mrmm)
    
    res3=cbind(mols2,mM2,mMM2,
               mrls2,mrm2,mrmm2)
    
    op2=mse(res1)
    OP2=cbind(OP2,op2)
    op3=mad(res3)
    OP3=cbind(OP3,op3)
    
  }
  
  MSE=mee(t(OP2))
  MAD=mee(t(OP3))
  
  
  
  nam=c("OLS","M","MM","Ridge-OLS","Ridge-M","Ridge-MM")
  
  data.frame(nam,R,n,sig,p,po,py,fx,fy,MAD,MSE)
}


results=NULL
R=c(0.999)
n=c(100)
sig=c(5)
p=c(3)
po=c(0.2)
py=c(0.2)
fx=c(5)
fy=c(5)

for(i in 1:length(R)){
  for(j in 1:length(n)){
    for(k in 1:length(sig)){
      for(l in 1:length(p)){
        for(m in 1:length(po)){
          for(nn in 1:length(py)){
            for(o in 1:length(fx)){
              for(pp in 1:length(fy)){
                results=rbind(results,umar(R=R[i],n=n[j],sig=sig[k],p=p[l],
                                           po=po[m],py=py[nn],fx=fx[o],fy=fy[pp]))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

View(results)
```

Comment: Please do not post code that contains `rm(list=ls())`. Someone who is trying to help you may accidentally delete all of the objects in their global environment.

Comment: ok, I remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't go through your code. If you are using robust optimization, you should also use robust measures, otherwise you won't achieve your goal.

I will try to show this with a simple example, just one case, without CV. Suppose these random data with the last point being a huge outlier.

```
set.seed(1)
x=1:100
y=x+rnorm(100)
y[100]=1000
```

Now we fit OLS and estimate the MSE

```
mean((predict(lm(y~x))-y)^2)
[1] 7779.713
```

and a robust linear model

```
library(MASS)
mean((predict(rlm(y~x,method="MM"))-y)^2)
[1] 8099.502
```

As you can see, the robust model has a higher MSE than the regular OLS model. Because that's exactly what OLS is minimizing! The mean squared error. While the robust model optimizes a different cost/loss function. So it is not surprising that OLS returns the best result.

As mentioned in the beginning, if you are doing robust optimization, you should use robust measures. If you check the MdAE of both models you will find that the robust model performs better (again, obviously, since this is its goal).

```
> median(abs(predict(lm(y~x))-y))
[1] 13.57675
> median(abs(predict(rlm(y~x,method="MM"))-y))
[1] 0.6008375
```

Comment: ok, you compare OLS with robust MM. I am also comparing Least absolute Regression. In this case, I can not use MSE because it will give the lowest result for OLS.  Also, I can not use MdAE because it will give the lowest result for the Least absolute Regression. So, what measure should I use in that case (when I have OLS, Least absolute and MM).

Comment: @jeza That is what you have to decide. You must first define what it is that you actually want to minimize, whether it is MSE, MAE, MdAE, or some other measure, and then compare this same measure across different models. Some models will be better by default, because they will be more closely aligned to your measure, but that is OK, because that is what you want to minimize. If you have outliers in your data then it is sensible to use a robust measure, since non-robust measures might give you very misleading results. All that is left is to decide which robust measure, MdAE would be classic.

Comment: @jeza No, multicollinearity will have to be dealt with another way. You can still use MdAE to check which model performs better, regardless of multicollinearity, if prediction is your goal. In case of prediction multicollinearity is not necessarily an issue, as long as the model predicts well.

Comment: Is it acceptable to measure MdE (Median Error) without absolute values? If not why?

Comment: @jeza In general, no. Suppose you have only 2 measurements, one with error -100 and the other with error +100, the mean (or median) would be 0, which is quite misleading. In other words, the me(di)an errors will cancel out, giving you a much more optimistic result.

Comment: Thanks. The last comment> Is it ok to calculate MSE on the same data. (not unseen data). Does this affect the results negatively?  OR CV and 70:30 split.

Comment: @jeza You should measure it on a separate data set or using CV, so as to not measure it on a possibly overfit model.